# Auto-focus the revealed text input upon clicks on the filter button in the review queues

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, design, user-experience

Currently, after I click the filter button in the review queue and the text input appears, `document.activeElement` is `document.body`. It would be a nice quality of life feature if the text input element was focused instead—at the very least—only if the text input is currently empty. I don't have a strong opinion on what should happen if the input isn't empty. Perhaps to put the caret at the end of the text input content.